# ThreadPoolExecutor and running background infinite loops

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I started working on this CV project and began it with using threading.  I need the output of the functions though, so I switched to ThreadPoolExecutor.  Admittedly I am new to using threading in general.  I realize that if I run these functions, the loops obviously wont loop anymore once it hits the return value.  At the same time, it seems like I can't just dump the value into a global variable either.  What's the best way to go about this??

function 1 is constantly updating a single image:

```
def imageWindow():
    while True:
        window = FindWindow(None, "Webull Desktop")
        rect = GetWindowRect(window)
        image = ImageGrab.grab((rect))
        image_arr = np.array(image)
        cv2.namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, image_arr)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key > 0:
            break
        return image
```

function 2 is constantly reporting which template from an array has the highest weight:

```
def weighTemplates():
    while True:
        weights = []
        for i in range(len(templates)):
            state = templates[i]['status']
            threshold = templates[i]['threshold']
            template = templates[i]['image']
            certainty = check_template(image, template, True)
            certainty = certainty * 100
            templates[i]['results'] = certainty
        for i in range(len(templates)):
            weights.append(templates[i]['results'])
        max_certainty = max(weights)
        max_index = weights.index(max_certainty)
        return templates[max_index]['status']
```

...
...
The rest...

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    t1 = executor.submit(imageWindow)
    image = t1.result()
    if image is not None:
        t2 = executor.submit(weighTemplates,image)
        state = t2.result()
```

What is the best way to keep `imageWindow` constantly running, updating `image`, and `weighTemplates` constantly running, updating `state` asynchronously, so that other work can be happening based on these constantly updated values?

Comment: you can't use `return` in `while`-loop - because `return` ends function and exit it. And you should assign result to globla variable or use `queue` to send it to main thread which should run `loop` which all time check if there is new value in queue and get value and assign to variable in main thread.

Comment: if you want to run function for single image then you don't need `while True` - and if you want run code in `while True` then you should use `queue` to get new value and return result.

Comment: @furas could you give an example of how to do this?  As I said earlier I'm new to threading and I really dont understand the various aspects of it.  If I try to set a global variable with a function called by an executor, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: at this moment I can only give link to [Increasing webcam FPS with Python and OpenCV - PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/) which show how to use `thread` to read frame for `cv.VideoCapture`. This code is also in module [imutils](https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils) in [filevideostream.py](https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/blob/master/imutils/video/filevideostream.py). I would use one thread only to gram image without displaying, second thread only to process image, and in main thread I would run loop to display it.